# Log should generate in JSON Format in Java

Tags: java, log4j

My requirement is to generate the logs in JSON format. I used logback.xml in my code and used the following link `https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output`

logback.xml look like below:-

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        <jsonFormatter
            class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
            <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
        </jsonFormatter>
        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="jsonLogger" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="json" />
</logger>
</configuration>
```

When I build the code using clean-install. It show the following message

```
15:02:23,374 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/C:/eclipse-workspace-16/EDW-JavaAgent/target/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
15:02:23,459 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
15:02:23,460 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
15:02:23,464 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [json]
15:02:23,591 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[json] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
15:02:23,591 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[json] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
15:02:23,591 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[json] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
15:02:23,592 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [jsonLogger] to TRACE
15:02:23,592 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [json] to Logger[jsonLogger]
15:02:23,592 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
15:02:23,593 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@3e3047e6 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

But my log is not converted into the JSON format. Need your help to generate the Log in JSON format.

Thank you

Regards
Amit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following code in logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>

                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any log with Level = TRACE in the console output you have shared. They are INFO, WARN etc but no TRACE.

Works for me

```
11:14:29,555 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [json] to Logger[jsonLogger]
11:14:29,555 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:14:29,556 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@2c34f934 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

{
  "timestamp" : "2022-09-02 11:14:29.566",
  "level" : "DEBUG",
  "thread" : "main",
  "logger" : "jsonLogger",
  "message" : "Debug message",
  "context" : "default"
}{
  "timestamp" : "2022-09-02 11:14:29.585",
  "level" : "TRACE",
  "thread" : "main",
  "logger" : "jsonLogger",
  "message" : "hello",
  "context" : "default"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other logging frameworks than just Logback...

https://github.com/elf4j/elf4j-engine

Put this one line in the *elf4j.properties* configuration file:

`pattern={json}` (minified one-line per log entry format)

or

`pattern={json:pretty}` (indented pretty print format)

**Disclaimer**: I am the dev of elf4j-engine.